# Signed Applet mix code under J7u21or J7u40 gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, security, applet, classnotfoundexception, signed

Please be aware this has been posted on Oracle Java Forum at 
https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2577877

I have a simple applet which shows a graph; this applet has two jar file, the main jar file is signed by a trusted CA and the other jar file is unsigned

in the manifest for the signed jar file, I have added

```
Trusted-Library value="true"
```

When applet starts from the java console when it tries to invoke a create object on the class from the unsigned jar file, I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` for the given class from the unsigned jar.

I have tried this on  window 7 Chrome and Internet explorer based on variety of Java 7 release (40, 21 on internet explorer and release 6 on Chrome)

It does not work.

If I signed the second jar file, it works fine.

Please notice, I do not want to bypass the check for mix code from java configuration.

Any idea or hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It should be `Trusted-Library: true` in the manifest..

Comment: It is added  already  in the manifest. I opened the manifest and checked that it is there. Please ready carefully the post

Comment: Please read carefully my comment.  In fact, do more than that.  Select the `gray text` in it and do a 'find' on that string in this page.  There are currently two hits for it, and ***neither*** is in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is confirmed by the  post  https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2280127

and it is confirmed by Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html#trusted_library

"Code in a jar file that is to be marked with the Trusted-Library manifest attribute may need to be modified slightly if it uses calls that are class loader dependent [...]
Code in a Trusted-Library can look up the normal loader by invoking Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().[...]
Generally, care must be taken to ensure that the code in the trusted library is written in a careful and secure manner and is otherwise compatible with being loaded in a separate class loader instance from any remaining jars which are part of the application and are loaded by the normal loader."

"Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().[...]"

I just did a simple test to call a method from a trusted jar into sandbox jar, I used reflection to do that and it worked.

It seems for every usage of any sandbox jar file classes in the trusted jar file, we have to use reflection ( load the class, invoke the required method ). Is this the way forward. Can somebody confirm this.

private void useReflection()
   {
      try
      {

```
       // using normal class loader 
     Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.abc.bla.bla.SandBox", true, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
     Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor();
     Object obj = constructor.newInstance(new Object[] {});

     Method method = clazz.getMethod("sayHello", new Class[] {});
     method.invoke(obj, new Object[] {});
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

In summary, it seems we have to use reflection in order to load the sandbox jar file (untrusted) to allow the use of normal class loader and to avoid the default one via import statement which is a special one designed for signed (trusted) jar file which is in a mix mode as per manifest additional attribute.